# Usar IF no Pyautogui em Python(automação)

Tags: python, automatização, pyautogui

estou tentando fazer um pedaço de um código que ele fica clicando para o lado automaticamente(com automação) e quero que quando eu clicar determinada tecla ele pare de funcionar.Eu não sei o que coloco no "IF" pra ele parar de funcionar, nao sei como posso dizer "se eu clicar tal coisa pare de funcionar com o break". Aluguem help por favor...

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.keyDown("alt")
pyautogui.press(["tab"])
pyautogui.keyUp("alt")
while True:
    pyautogui.press(["left"])
    if 
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

O PyAutoGUI somente realiza a automação, ele ainda não consegue detectar esse tipo de evento no computador. O que você pode fazer é usar, em conjunto do PyAutoGUI, a biblioteca [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/).

```py
import pyautogui
from pynput import mouse

# Este é o callback para os eventos de click do mouse
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left and pressed:
        # Retornar False para a execução do listener de eventos
        print("Clicou!")
        return False

pyautogui.keyDown("alt")
pyautogui.press(["tab"])
pyautogui.keyUp("alt")

# Listener irá verificar quando o mouse clicará
with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    while True:

        # Assim que o mouse clicar, o listener irá encerrar e parar o loop
        if not listener.running:
            break

        pyautogui.press(["left"])
```